# Array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to found the place of 1 digit in array and the number of 0 digit before 1. It means in the below array I need to achieve `placeOfOne=3` `numberOfZeros=2` in:

```
a = [0 0 1 0]
```

Do we have any function for this? Best, Elnaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your example, I'm assuming your input vector contains only binary values of "1" and "0".

If you're looking for the position of "1"s, use `find` like everyone suggested. The number of zeros should always be the position of the "1" minus the number of preceding "1"s:

```
placeOfOne = find(a);
numberOfZeros = placeOfOne - (1:numel(placeOfOne));
```

If you're looking only for the first "1", add a second parameter. This reduces to:

```
placeOfOne = find(a, 1);
numberOfZeros = placeOfOne - 1;
```

Comment: It should be find(a,1) instead of find(a,'first'). This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the place of 1

```
placeOfOne = find(a)
```

And then sum up the zeros before that:

```
numberOfZeros = sum(a(1:placeOfOne)  == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`isMember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function, if there are elements other than 0 and 1.

Also, if there are just 0 and 1, the number of zeros should just be `(position of 1) - 1`, should it?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach

```
a = [0 0 1 0];
placeOfOne = find(a==1);
digitsBeforeOne = a(1:placeOfOne);
numberOfZeros= length(find(digitsBeforeOne ==0));
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, I was unaware of the nnz function